# Unpredictable string length when second argument of cin.getline() is greater than the length of array

Tags: c++, arrays, string

```
using namespace std;
char str1[10],str2[10];
cin.getline(str1,14);
cin.getline(str2,10);
cout<<strlen(str1)<<'\t'<<strlen(str2);
```

The Output of the above code was as follows-

```
1234567890123
bye
13         3
```

How could be the length of str1 greater than 10?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346806/what-is-segmentation-fault

Comment: This is why you should use `std::string` for input.

Answer (score 4):

It can't. You overran your buffer and overwrote memory outside of the array. Your program happened not to crash or teleport a cat into your monitor before it found a `'\0'` no earlier than 13 bytes in memory from the start of your 10-element array.

Answer (score 3):

The behaviour of your overrunning a `char` array is *undefined*. To be clear, you need to ensure there is sufficient space for your data **and** a `\0` string terminator else the behaviour of `cout` will be undefined.

The compiler is allowed to do *anything* if it encounters this.

Your output is a common manifestation, but you must **not** rely on such behaviour.

Comment: Then why there was not any runtime error related to segmentation fault? My compiler is g++4.8.2 running on gnome terminal of Ubuntu 14

Comment: Because your compiler was kind to you. It could have eaten your cat. That's the nature of undefined behaviour. C++ doesn't make what it considers to be unnecessary runtime checks.

Comment: @dlpcoder: Segmentation faults are not guaranteed every time you overrun a buffer (generally only when you overrun it so much that you're requesting from the OS memory that's on an inaccessible virtual memory page, or dereferencing a null pointer). Many (most?) security exploits rely on this fact.

Answer (score 0):

Because it is likely to use the space reserved for str2.
But this is undefined behaviour, it could do anything (likely a segfault(access violation or whatever is named on your OS)

Comment: _"it is likely to use the space reserved for str2"_ Is it?